# Python skl: Export a decision tree (regression) in text form including the MSE

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to output the Regression Tree structure in text form using the following code

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3)
model = regressor.fit(X, y, sample_weight=weights)

text_representation = tree.export_text(decision_tree=regressor,
                                       feature_names=list(X.columns),
                                       spacing=5,
                                       decimals=3)
print(text_representation)
```

This outputs the value at each node. But it does not include the MSE at each node. It also does not include the number of samples at each node.

If I add `show_weights=True` to the code it doesn't change anything.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like [`export_text`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b611bf873bd5836748647221480071a87/sklearn/tree/_export.py#L923) includes those attributes.  You could write your own starting from the current implementation.

Comment: See also the example https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html